# WHERE statement based on variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to filter a SELECT statament. The behavior I want is that if the parameter @productId = % then I want the WHERE clause to do the following:

```
WHERE (DTH.TaskId IS NULL OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId)
```

If @productId does not = % I want the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (PDT.PK_Product = @productId)
```

I am having trouble achieving this.

I have tried case statements but couldn't get it to make sense. I have also tried:

```
WHERE IF @productId = '%' (
        DTH.TaskId IS NULL
        OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId
        ) ELSE (
        PDT.PK_Product = @productId
        )
```

THis is causing syntax errors. How do I achieve the desired results?

Comment: LIKE opertator requires character data type on the left. Your `PDT.PK_Product` is not a character data type. What are you trying to achieve with `PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId`? That is, what result are you expecting?

Comment: Tell us in words what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WHERE
  (@productId = '%' AND (DTH.TaskId IS NULL OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId))
  OR
  (NOT @productId = '%' AND (PDT.PK_Product = @productId))
```

Comment: I see where you are coming from. This makes sense. But I am getting the error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.

Comment: Right, because you have productID param as INT. You might need to use INT then but use NULL value instead of '%'.

Comment: If you leave it INT, then you can't use LIKE in first statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
--assumes -1 and 0 are invalid TaskIds
WHERE PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId 
    OR coalesce(DTH.TaskId, -1) = case when @productId = '%' THEN -1 ELSE coalesce(DTH.TaskID,0) END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT..
FROM..
WHERE @productId = '%' AND (DTH.TaskId IS NULL OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId)

UNION

SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE @productId != '%' AND PDT.PK_Product = @productId
```